# Arduinos IDE Serial Monitor works while XCode popen() does not.

Tags: xcode, macos, arduino, popen

I am trying to communicate with my Arduino through popen() function. I wrote a simple Mac App in XCode:

```
    - (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    popen("echo hello world > /dev/tty.usbmodem1411", "r");
}
```

And here is the Arduino Code:

```
int redPin = 8;
int greenPin = 9;
int bluePin = 10;

int inByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup()
{
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(8000); 
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // get incoming byte:
    inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(inByte);
    setColor(inByte,inByte,inByte);
    delay(1000);
    setColor(0,0,0);
  }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(greenPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluePin, blue);
}
```

Now, when I try to use Arduino Serial Monitor and write some gibberish there my LED's light up fine and I see that it is working. When I run my XCode program, press the button, nothing happens. I did set break points and I did check that the line of code gets executed. I double checked the serial port, it is all fine, but no luck. It still does not work.

Comment: have you tried changing `if` to `while` ?

Comment: I tried that, did not help. Still the same thing - serial port working while popen() does not.

Comment: Have your tried `echo hello world > /dev/tty.usbmodem1411`in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I solved the problem by using IOKit/ioctl. I am still not sure why popen() did not work, might be because Arduino IDE was using the port and thus it was not available, however IOKit works like a charm. Plus it allows more control and flexibility, you can actually search for ports before you start and see if they are available. If anyone runs in to the same problem check http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Cocoa#IOKit. Thanks for all help.